# Many-to-Many Relation Table Reference in Calculated SQL Query - App Maker

Tags: mysql, google-app-maker

I have two tables, WaterUseData and PermitList with a many-to-many relation that is captured in a table with a name designation of 'WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits' in the default database. I am running a calculated sql datasource against the WaterUseData table where the RelatedPermits key is equal to a parameter of type Permit key that I pass from the client. The relevant query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS WaterYear,
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '10',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Oct',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '11',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Nov',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '12',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Dec',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '01',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jan',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '02',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Feb',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '03',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Mar',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '04',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Apr',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '05',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'May',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '06',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jun',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '07',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jul',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '08',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Aug',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '09',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Sep',
  SUM(Water_Use_Gallons) as Total
FROM WaterUseData
WHERE [WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits].RelatedPermits = :PermitKey
GROUP BY YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
ORDER BY YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ASC
```

Besides the [WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits] in an attempt to reference the table holding the relation keys I have also tried 'WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits', "WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits", *'WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits*', ['WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits'], ["WaterUseDataPermits - RelatedPermits"], and WaterUseDataPermits_RelatedPermits. All of these have resulted in an error in the SQL syntax or an error due to a reference to an unknown column.

Other answers I have found in regards to referencing relation tables have only suggested to include the table name for the relation keys like My_Relation_Table but the table name in App Maker does not appear to conform to this type of naming convention. If anyone might be able to help me solve this problem I would appreciate it.

Added images of of the relevant tables. There are no foreign key fields in either table and the field 'WR_Number' that both tables contain is no longer relevant since App Maker uses a customized relation API.

[image: PermitList Table]

[image: WaterUse Table]

Comment: Please post the structure of WaterUseData and PermitList tables.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I posted images for the fields contained within each table. Since this is a database that gets set up for the application in App Maker specifically I do not have access to the actual structure as I don't have access to the Cloud SQL console. However, when doing an export to Google Sheets it does export the relation table which just shows key pairs between the two tables. I hope this helps and thank you for checking in on this. Let me know if you may need anything else.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I see now the importance of asking for the structure of the table and thanks to somebody else's help in the Google-App-Maker Google group I was able to get the table structure and name and thereby adjust my query to get the desired result. I will be posting my own answer how I was able to accomplish this.

Comment: Glad to see that your problem is resolved now. The main motto of Stackoverflow is accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the useful insight posted by Bruce under the Googe-App-Maker user group here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/wovN3w3TpT4 I was able to use Calculated SQL models to get a list of all my tables within my database and then I used an additional SQL command to fetch the correct column names within the relation table resulting in an adjusted query that solved my problem. Here are the steps I took to accomplish this:

1. Created a calculated SQL model, called it 'Tables', created one
   Field of type string and set the name setting of the field to
   'Tables_in_MyDatabaseKey'. Set the datasource query to `show
   tables;`. Created a blank page, created a list widget with
   datasource set to 'Tables', created a label widget within the list
   row and set binding to `@datasource.item.Tables_in_MyDatabaseKey`.
   This resulted in being able to see the correct table name of my
   relation table.
2. Created an other calculated SQL model, called it 'TableDescription',
   created one Field of type string and set the name setting of the
   field to 'Field'. Set the datasource query to `DESCRIBE
   MyDBTableName;` (This portion has been edited to change DESCRIPTION to DESCRIBE, thank you to @Morfinismo for pointing out this error). Added another list widget to my newly created page
   and set the datasource to 'TableDescription', created a label widget
   within this list row and set binding to `@datasource.item.Field`.
   This displayed the correct column names within my table.

The corrected SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS WaterYear,
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '10',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Oct',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '11',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Nov',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '12',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Dec',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '01',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jan',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '02',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Feb',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '03',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Mar',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '04',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Apr',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '05',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'May',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '06',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jun',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '07',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Jul',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '08',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Aug',
  SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m') = '09',Water_Use_Gallons,null)) as 'Sep',
  SUM(Water_Use_Gallons) as Total
FROM WaterUseData, WaterUseDataPermits_HAS_Permits
WHERE WaterUseData.id = WaterUseDataPermits_HAS_Permits.WaterUseDataPermits_fk AND WaterUseDataPermits_HAS_Permits.Permits_fk = :PermitKey
GROUP BY YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
ORDER BY YEAR(Date + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) ASC
```

Comment: For the `TableDescription` I was getting a SQL query syntax error when using `Description MyDBTableName;`. Instead I literally ended up using `SELECT Column_name FROM Information_schema.columns WHERE Table_name like 'WaterUseData_Has_PermitList'`. Does the `DESCRIPTION` word should be something else in your example?

Comment: @Morfinismo I was just using a placeholder in this example, the actual code used was `DESCRIPTION WaterUseDataPermits_HAS_Permits` and that gave the correct results.

Comment: I tried that also, and it still gave me an SQL syntax error. Very weird but thanks anyways! Excellent post btw.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... Instead of using `DESCRIPTION` I used `DESCRIBE` and then it worked.

Comment: @Morfinismo Thank you for catching this error. I have edited the answer to reflect this.